# How do I put a try and except inside of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

K, I've redone the code:

```
def KiloToMile():
    try:
        kilos = input('Please insert the amount of kilometers there are: ')
        calc = (kilos/1.609344)
        raise NameError
    except ValueError:
        print('Oops! Please insert a valid number.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Oops! Please insert only numbers.')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Oops! You can not enter zero.')
    except:
        print('Oops! Please try again.')


KiloToMile() # prints 'Oops! Please try again.'
```

I've been using bing ai to help, but it refuses to let me use general excepts. This is my second attempt.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: the `except` needs to be at the same indentation level as the `try`

Comment: @LordElrond I tried that, but it now says Indentation Error.

Comment: `try..except` is really well explained by many tutorials on the basics of python. Peruse one such tutorial and learn the concept instead of asking an AI to write your code for you.

Comment: See @tdelaney's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77069790/how-do-i-put-a-try-and-except-inside-of-a-function#comment135865942_77069817) below: Why do you `raise NameError`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've been learning Python in class, but I broke my leg, and had to miss a day, so I don't really know how try and except works in functions.

Comment: @Dux you should use `float` instead of `int` so you can pass decimals from the command line

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be using a generic except to begin with.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my teacher is making me use it :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `except` needs to be at the same indentation level as `try`.
Also, the generic `except`, which catches *all* errors, needs to be last.

Also, any arguments given from the command line are strings, so you will need to convert the value to a number via `float`:

```
def KiloToMile():
    try:
        kilos = float(input('Please insert the amount of kilometers there are: '))
        calc = (kilos/1.609344)
        print(calc)
    except ValueError:
        print('Oops! Please insert a valid number.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Oops! Please insert only numbers.')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Oops! You can not enter zero.')
    except:
        print('Oops! Please try again.')
```

Furthermore, you only need to catch a `TypeError`, which will be thrown when letters are passed to the input:

```
def KiloToMile():
    try:
        kilos = float(input('Please insert the amount of kilometers there are: '))
        calc = (kilos/1.609344)
        print(calc)
    except ValueError:
        print('Oops! Please insert a valid number.')
```

Comment: I've tried that one, and now all it is saying is Oops! Please try again.

Edit 1: OML I'm slow.

Comment: Your example code doesn't have any, well, code to it. Just the error handlers. This example inserted a `raise NameError` where you didn't have anything at all - because _something_ needs t o be there, Since you don't specifically catch `NameError` , it flows to the naked `except`. You would replace `raise NameError` with your own code that needs protecting with exception handlers.

Comment: Don't use a generic `except`, it catches things like keyboardinterrupt

Comment: @tdelaney OP doesn't have any code to test.  My intent was to show how the generic except works, and to fix the indentation and syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah, I added the OML I'm slow cause I saw the comment and realized I was just being slow, so mb

Comment: I've just redid the code though, so it now has code in it.

Comment: @LordElrond So... I've actually just been slow and y'all have been carrying me through like a baby. I didn't really read everything. I've just realized what I needed. My bad. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: With this approach, you only accept integers as value. One cannot calculate how many miles are in 1.6 km

Comment: @MSH that is the point, the purpose of the function is to convert kilometers to miles.

Comment: @LordElrond But you only accept whole numbers.

Comment: Sorry y'all for being so dumb this entire time. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @MSH good point, I fixed that

Comment: @Dux You're welcome.  Keep studying.